# Whats the best way to create summary records from detail records with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I have maybe 10 to 20 million detail records coming in a day (statistical and performance data), that must be read in, and summarized into 24 hourly and 1 daily summary records.

The process calculates averages on several fields, gets the max and min values of others, nothing significant CPU wise.

Is it better to:

A) summarize the detail records into the summary records while the records are coming in, delaying each detail record insert slightly?  I assume there will be a lot of locking (select for update's etc) in the summary tables, as there are several different systems importing data.

B) wait until the hour is over, and then select the entire previous hours data and create the summary records?  There would be a delay for users to see the statistics, however the detail records would be available during the time.

Perhaps there are alternative methods to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `view` for summary tables. Your all insert will work as usual. Just make views according to your need as summary. That will update automatically  with main tables.

Also you can make the 24 hourly and 1 daily summary basis. Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set. A view acts as a virtual table.

For more details about views refer : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Let me know if you want further assistance regarding `mysql views.`

Comment: I am just concerned about the queries that create it will kill the server, otherwise, why would I not just create the same queries for the run-time reports instead of creating a view?  There are 5 billion rows in the database currently.  Perhaps I am missing something (the advantage of views?)

Comment: Does MYSQL support Materialized Views?

Answer (score 0):

It'd depend on the load required to run the single update, but I'd probably go with a separate summary run. I'd probably put a small bet on saying that a single update would take a shorter amount of time than the cumulative on-every-insert idea.